# How to create Array of buttons in android using java

Tags: android

I want to create an array of buttons in my app. So how that can be done. Secondly, is it possible to interact with each button in an array of buttons? If so, how? Please suggest to me.

Regards
Anshuman

Comment: Give us an example of what you've got so far. We're not your personal code monkeys.

Comment: Yeah, that's possible. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside you Activity do something like this:

```
    LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(this);
    linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);       

    ArrayList<Button> ab = new ArrayList<Button>();
    for (Button b : ab) {       
        linear.addView(b);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    };
    setContentView(linear);
```

Comment: If you want to find each button then give also an ID to each one. To later use findViewById.